# Errors during compilation: Magezon\Core\Block\Adminhtml\TopMenu Incompatible argument type: Required type:

Tags: magento2.4

Getting Errors during compilation:
Magezon\Core\Block\Adminhtml\TopMenu

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 

        $data
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }
```

Please suggest

Answer (score -1):

**Change following code**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 

        $data
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }
```

**To below code**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        $data
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }
```